# What is difference between $node and $content in drupal?

Tags: templates, drupal-theming

Can Any one help me getting difference between $node and $content in drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Both are just variables, but with predefined values for some places, so $node - usually just the node object(node is a piece of individual content of any content type).
$content - that is just variable that have different values depends on where it is used, for example in node template $content - array of node items, in block template - that is rendered block content...